# What is Markdown for underscore/underline? Is there any?

Tags: support, markdown

Is there a way to make underscored/underlined text?

I read editing help and there seem to be nothing about that. By *underscored* I mean what in HTML is done with `<u>...</u>`:

```html
Alice wanted to <u>emphasize</u> that her dress is fabulous.
```

"Layman's logic" would suggest using actual underscore `_` to create such feat but *it make things italicized*.

So question remains - is there a way to underscore a text?

Comment: you mean display something like a\_b? Or did you mean you want to underline some text?

Comment: Does escaping with a backslash work for underscores? \_Yes it does\_. Unless you mean _underlined_, of course

Comment: By *underscored* I mean what in HTML is done with `<u> blah blah blah</u>`.

Comment: Escaping \_ makes underscore characted visible, I wanted to underscore text.

Comment: Shall I say underline? Is that apply to title? Can/should I change it?

Comment: I will edit the question and change it to "underscore/underline" because everyone seems tu use the latter although [dictionary says](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/underscoring) *"underscore: A line drawn under writing or text to indicate emphasis or italic type"*.

Answer (score 1):

An underscore is simply the _ character but it's pretty clear from your description you actually mean underlining i.e. drawing a line underneath some text.

The markdown that Stack supports is pretty standard and standard markdown doesn't support underlining. Presumably this is because in HTML underlining is generally used as part of the indication that the text works as a hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks, I read the answer. Saying that it's a "relic of typewriters and handwriting" and "bolding and putting everything in italics makes everything look better" it just an opinion based on taste.

Comment: Man pages disagree with this answer.